# r unlist function unexpected results

Tags: r

Trying to flatten a list to a vector I've just found an unexpected behaviour. To simplify let's do what `?unlist` proposes as an example:

```
unlist(options())
```

Look at the original list size:

```
length(unlist(options())) # 69 in my environment
```

Should the unlisted list retain its length? I would think so, but...

```
length(unlist(options())) # 79!!!
length(unlist(options(), use.names = F)) # Another 79
```

What is happening? I need to retain the list values but `unlist()` gives me an extra.

Comment: But `sum(lengths(options())) == 79`. `unlist` is doing what it should be doing. Some `list` elements have more than one item.

Comment: Thank you @AnandaMahto. I found this "problem" in a big data set but with the little `options()` I could't see it.

Comment: Sometimes a smaller example helps to see the behavior more clearly. I hope the example in my answer helped clarify this for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is because some of the list elements may have more than one value. Thus, `unlist` is doing exactly what it is being asked to do.

Look at the following examples:

```
L <- list(1, c(1, 2, 3), 1, c(4, 5))
length(L)         # 4        <<< How many list elements are there?
length(unlist(L)) # 7        <<< How many elements are there within the list?
lengths(L)        # 1 3 1 2  <<< How many elements are in each list element?
sum(lengths(L))   # 7        <<< How many elements should we expect from unlist?
```

If you only expected the first value for each, you can extract that alone using something like:

```
sapply(L, `[[`, 1)
# [1] 1 1 1 4
```

(Which is a vector equal to the length of the list, but has a good amount of data missing).